# unable to "yarn" upgrade to @react-native-firebase/firestore@7.3.0

Tags: yarnpkg

The new release launched yesterday, but until today I still couldn't upgrade to the latest release. My yarn repository configure:https://registry.yarnpkg.com. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?